# How to change UIPageViewController VCs by UIButton Swift 4.0?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uipageviewcontroller

I have UIPageViewController with 3 UIViewControllers ("FirstVC", "SecondVC", "ThirdVC"). 
ViewControllers changes by scroll, but I need to change its by click on UIButtons.

How I can do this?

Maybe some func, in which VC will setup by StoryboardID?

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Do you have a `UIPageViewController` embedded in a "parent" VC, and you want next/previous buttons to programmatically change the current page? Or are you just using a `UIPageViewController`, and you want buttons "in each page" to do the changing?

Comment: Yes, you understand my idea.
My UIPageVC embedded in ViewController like a Container
and under it there are button with names of UIPageVC VCs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily programmatically navigate through the pages of a `UIPageViewController` using:

```
setViewControllers([targetPage], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In the case where you have a `UIPageViewController` *embedded* in a ContainerView, and you want buttons in the "root" view to control the page view controller, the basic process is:

- add navigation methods (funcs) to your page view controller class
- save a reference to the page view controller when it is loaded have
- your buttons call the navigation funcs using that reference

When your "root" view controllers loads and instantiates the view controller that is embedded in your ContainerView, it calls `prepare(for segue:...)` - which is where you get your reference.

In Storyboard, where you embed your view controller in the ContainerView, you will see a standard "segue" connection. In the Attributes Inspector, give that segue an Identifier, such as "PageControllerEmbedSegue".

In your root controller class, add a class-level var:

```
var myPageVC: BasicPageViewController?
```

and in `prepare()`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // get a reference to the embedded PageViewController on load
    if let vc = segue.destination as? BasicPageViewController,
        segue.identifier == "PageControllerEmbedSegue" {
        self.myPageVC = vc
    }

}
```

Now, you can call functions / get properties of your embedded view controller.

I have a full example on GitHub: https://github.com/DonMag/EmbeddedPageView

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways. You could add a segue in the Storyboard file and call

`performSegue(withIdentifier: "toResponseTime", sender: self)`

otherwise you could do something like.

```
    let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AngelDetailViewController") as! AngelDetailViewController

    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Comment: Nope, this is for simply Pushing to View Controller. Page View Controller has some delegate methods that provides browsing embedded controllers.

Comment: so and how do this by delegate methods?